# Implementation of counts the number of "1"s in the binary representation of an integer

Tags: visual-studio, assembly

Please help! I have an Assembly code implementation of counts the number of "1"s in the binary representation of an integer in Microsoft Visual Studio.

I actually can compile with no error! But when run I got an unhandled exception :

```
**'lab2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'lab2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'lab2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
First-chance exception at 0x68A07310 (msvcr120d.dll) in lab2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x68A07310 (msvcr120d.dll) in lab2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
The program '[3356] lab2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).**
```

My code here :(

```
__declspec(naked) unsigned int countOnes(unsigned int x) {
   __asm{
    PUSH EAX
    PUSH EBX
    PUSH ECX
    PUSH EDX

    XOR EAX, EAX
    MOV EBX, [ESP + 20]
    XOR ECX, ECX
    MOV EDX, 1

FOR_LOOP:
    CMP ECX, 8
    JGE END_LOOP

    AND EDX, EBX
    CMP EDX, 1
    JE COUNT

NEXT:
    INC ECX
    XOR EDX, EDX
    SHL EDX, CL
    JMP FOR_LOOP

COUNT:
    INC EAX
    JMP NEXT

END_LOOP:
    ret
}
}
```

Comment: this sounds like an linker error so the code has nothing to do with it. Check your project settings the error message is rather self explanatory about what's wrong.

Comment: You forgot to pop all that stuff you pushed.

Comment: You could use: popcnt eax, dword ptr [esp + 20], if your compiler / assembler supports it. Your cpu should support it unless it's an old computer. There are also instrinsic functions _popcnt for microsoft, __builtin_popcnt for gcc.